# Defining states in Multi-State model

Tags: r, survival, censoring, interval-censoring, competing-risks

I am looking to build a multi state model some packages for instance in `R` are  for panel or intermittently observed data (`msm` package) which I believe would be interval censored data and others can be used to fit models where transitions times are known (packages such as `mstate` and `flexsurv`).  My question is to whether I have interval censored data or not.  I will be creating the 'states' based on weekly observations over a month. For simplicity if a variable is 1 to 3 -> low, 7-10 -> high else mid for each weekly state. Could I model these transitions as exact given I am defining the states or would this be interval censored? specifically  would my setup be best classifed as scenario 1,2, or 3 below TIA

From the `msm` package documentation [msm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/msm/msm.pdf)

1 An observation of the process at an arbitrary time (a "snapshot" of the process,
or "panel-observed" data). The states are unknown between observation
times.

2 An exact transition time, with the state at the previous observation retained
until the current observation. An observation may represent a transition to
a different state or a repeated observation of the same state (e.g. at the end
of follow-up). Note that if all transition times are known, more flexible
models could be fitted with packages other than msm - see the note under
exacttimes.
Note also that if the previous state was censored using censor, for example
known only to be state 1 or state 2, then obstype 2 means that either state 1 is retained or state 2 is retained until the current observation - this does
not allow for a change of state in the middle of the observation interval.

3 An exact transition time, but the state at the instant before entering this state is
unknown. A common example is death times in studies of chronic diseases.

Comment: 1. "Intermittently observed" is not the same thing as "interval-censored", nor is "panel data", so I'm not sure what the thinking behind your first sentence is.   2. If you define your states as "Low", "Medium", and "High", that's fine, and transitions between them are well-defined.

Comment: I'm referencing the documentation from the msm package my understanding must be off but regardless it and other literature seem to suggest whether you know  the exact time of the transition is important, I know the states are well defined  my question is about the timing around the definition as my research leads me to believe the answer will dictate which package I should be using.

Comment: @jbowman Thanks for the feedback,  I've modified my question a bit  could you give it a read?

Answer (score 0):

If you are observing the same individuals each week for 4 or 5 weeks, and the values of the outcome variable can change arbitrarily during each week between observations, then you have Scenario 1. As the quote puts it, you only take "a 'snapshot' of the process" once a week, and "the states are unknown between observation times."

Based on your description of the outcome values, you might be better off modeling this as an [ordinal regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/ordered-logit/info) instead. If you have outcome values on a scale of 1 to 10, it seems that you would be losing information by further categorizing the outcomes into "low," "middle" and "high." The [`ordinal`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/index.html) and [`GLMMadaptive`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=GLMMadaptive) packages in R can handle the repeated measures on the same individuals.

Comment: my thinking was that it was scenario 1 as well but since  the 'state' is created after observing  for a week then classifying  it as low, mid ,high which is a simplification of my process  it is based on a sum of several variables over that week.  So  the individuals can't change  during week because It is not a natural process but instead one I'm defining.  So I am just not sure.

Comment: Also the goal is to see which covariates influence movement between states I will investigate the `GLMMadaptive ` to see how that could be implemented